# Different Result with ROUND Function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rounding, mysql-8.0

I have a table containing column of type DOUBLE, it has value `2.5` in it. When I provide this as an argument to round function i.e. `round(columnName)`, the result is `2`.
 However, when I pass `2.5` hardcoded to the round function, the result is `3`.
Why is the round function not showing correct data when column name is supplied as an argument? Attached are the screenshots of the problem.[image]

Comment: I'm wondering if your DOUBLE value 2.5 is actually something like 2.499999 which as a result gets rounded down to 2. Depending on the IDE you are using, you might be able to change how the value is displayed.

Comment: Here's a [simplified snippet to reproduce the issue](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d31bc7440b48154fd5ace619509f062). `DOUBLE` is not an exact type so you've probably hit a precision issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment of @Alvaro. I changed the data type of column from `DOUBLE` to `DECIMAL`. And the issue is resolved. Strange but true.
Now the `ROUND` function is bringing in the correct results.